Using the llama3 new template
This is the current template that works for the other llms i am using. However  I want to get this system working with a llama3.
# Prompt
template = """Based on the table schema below, write a SQLite query that would answer the user's question:
{schema}

Question: {question}
SQL Query:"""  # noqa: E501

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", "Given an input question, convert it to a SQL query. No pre-amble."),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", template),
    ]
)

And after intensive research I found out llama3 has it's own special template format. Which looks like this.
template = """
        <|begin_of_text|>
        <|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>
        {system_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>
        {user_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>
        """

So i really need to use the new template with my code. Please if I really need your assistance to turn the previous template code to this new format.
Thank you

load the tokenizer using transformers library
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model, trust_remote_code=True)

specify the chat history
msgs =[
        ("system", "Given an input question, convert it to a SQL query. No pre-amble."),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", template),
    ]

convert it into the prompt
prompt = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(msgs, add_generation_prompt=True, tokenize=False)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
